# Always 403 denied acces in symfony 2 despite my user have the role in database

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-security

I have always 403 denied access , 
this is my security.yml

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        Livreur:       Livreur
        Producteur:    Producteur
        Admin:         Admin

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: Admin }
```

i want to acces to {url}/app_dev.php/admin , always 403 !

i am using mongodb database and this is my document in mongo :

> 

```
db.User.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54fef590a98a93842000002e"),
        "username" : "admin",
        "usernameCanonical" : "admin",
        "email" : "admin@email.com",
        "emailCanonical" : "admin@email.com",
        "enabled" : true,
        "salt" : "flxrknwannwow0swccwk000gw44kwgg",
        "password" : "u8d6fIrwTGF/x2FYhJxootw8MU4PR3KvY5mUjwLn9ZPBxA1foi0ox/OVif
9HIipz/cTIdvghJNKsdXljCR6MVA==",
        "locked" : false,
        "expired" : false,
        "roles" : {
                "0" : "Admin"
        },
        "firstName" : "xxxx",
        "lastName" : "xxx",
        "numTel" : "xxxx",
        "adresse" : "xxxxx",
        "lastLogin" : ISODate("2015-03-10T14:22:38Z")
}

the return of $document->getRoles() is 
["ADMIN","ROLE_USER"]
```

and if if i make test for current user i get :

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('Admin') 
or
$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ADMIN')
```

it return always FALSE

Help please

Comment: i find the solution 
Any role must have this prefix "ROLE" , so i add ROLE_** to my 3 Roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that all role-names should begin with ROLE_ - prefix
You need to use ROLE_ADMIN.
I had similar problem, but when I changed role name - problem has been resolved.